# Group by example from SQL to pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I am trying to find how many duplicates I have for a pair of values in a table.
The columns are "A" and "B"
I can do

```
select A, B, count(*) as counter from table group by A, B
```

In fact, I could also do

```
select A, B from (select A, B, count(*) as counter from table group by A, B) where counter >= 2
```

to only deal with values that have n duplicates.

How can I do the same in pandas?

I can do

```
df.groupby(["A", "B"].count(),
```

but that gives me every element, I only want to limit to those where count>=2

For example if I have:

```
   A  B  C
0  x  a  1
1  x  a  1
2  x  b  2
3  y  b  3
4  y  a  1
```

I want to identify the first two columns because groupby() gives count of 2 (the pair (x,a) is repeated).
I would like to do the same for any value, not just 2.

Comment: Can you show us some sample data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can do filter after `groupby`

```
df.groupby(["A", "B"])['A'].count().loc[lambda x : x>2]
```

Update `duplicated`

```
df[df.duplicated(['A','B'],keep=False)]
Out[1178]: 
   A  B  C
0  x  a  1
1  x  a  1
```

`transform` for different n

```
n=2

df[df.groupby(['A','B'])['A'].transform('count')==n]
```

Comment: What if I want the count =3, or something larger?

Comment: Thank you! Why do I need ['A"] before .transform? What does that do? Can I put any column?

Comment: @user that is just require for count , you need something to `count` .

Comment: So, I guess there is no option like * in sql? What if my column had a null in it?

Comment: @user if you need count all you can `df.groupby(['A','B']).transform('count')
`

Comment: No, that is not what I meant. The first answer is good, thank you